# Who is referred to whom?

Tags: word-order

In my business, sometimes clients I have done work for will provide my name and contact information to other, potential clients.  I send a Thank You card to the referring (original) client. What should be the correct wording? "Dear Joe, Thank you for referring Mary to me for ..." or "Dear Joe, Thank you for referring me to Mary for ..."

Comment: ' ... passing on my contact details ...'.

Answer (score 1):

As he is giving out your card to them, he is referring you to them.
"Dear Joe, Thank you for referring me to Mary for ..."

(Edited to add I like Edwin's suggestion... "passing on my contact details".)